# .chm creator for Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, software-rec, chm

I'm trying to create a `.chm` file on a Mac, but can't seem to find an application to do it.

Are there any `.chm` creators for OS X?

Comment: What sort of a file is a .chm?

Comment: Why do you need CHM?

Comment: A .chm is a [Microsoft Compiled HTML Help file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help).

Answer (score 0):

Not really, you could potentially run [Sandcastle](http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=SHFB) under Darwine or a virtual machine.

Or if you're feeling adventurous you could try using the [FreePascal CHM package](http://wiki.freepascal.org/chm)

It looks like both [AurigaDoc](http://aurigadoc.sourceforge.net/) and [DocBook](http://docbook.sourceforge.net/) can export to .chm as well

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [HelpLogic](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/15605/helplogic) will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of [Free Pascal](http://www.freepascal.org) (2.4.4 and newer) also have a basic commandline CHM compiler (not just library form). The command is named **chmcmd**